# Подключение .c файлов

Tags: c

Вот мучает меня долгое время вопрос. Почему нельзя подключать .c файлы? 
К примеру, у меня есть 2 файла:

**main.c**

```
#include "functions.c"
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", Sum(1, 2));
}
```

и

**functions.c**

```
int Sum(int n1, int n2) {
    return n1 + n2;
}
```

Почему когда я пытаюсь скомпилировать код, у меня вылетает кучу ошибок линковки?
Что делать?
[image: Ошибки]

P.S Я знаю что обычно делают это всё через заголовочные файлы, но всё же интересно почему это не сделать через .c файл. И если можно, то как?

Comment: А называть функции **одинаково** кто будет - Дейкстра? Вы же в `functions.c` записали одну функцию, а вызываете другую!!!

Comment: подключать `c` файл можно. Даже jpg, если знать как. Но вот включать в компиляцию этот файл не стоит

Comment: @Harry Уже поправил, спасибо что подметили. Но не в этом основная проблема.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо за ответы. @ヒミコ подсказал не использовать Visual Studio. И это оказалось действенным способом. В данном случае для решения этой проблемы я использовал Visual Studio Code и компилятор GCC. 
UDP: Добавлю ещё что на самом деле ошибку ещё можно решить с помощью исключением файла из компиляции. В Visul Studio, ПКМ -> Исключить из проекта. За эту наводку спасибо так-же ヒミコ.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы не хотите писать заголовочный файл, то не подключайте ваш `.c` файл, а просто напишите перед `main`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int Sum(int n1, int n2);

int main(void) { // в си нужно явно указывать что функция не принимает параметров.
    printf("%d\n", Sum(1, 2));
}
```

Либо при поключении файла, не передавайте его компилятору.

Comment: При чем тут это? Человек спрашивал совершенно о другом. И проблемы у него другие...

Comment: `extern` вроде не в тему.

Comment: Ну как минимум при том что у него файл передается на компиляцию.

Comment: @Harry, проблемы как раз в этом.

Comment: @Qwertiy Да ни хрена! Проблема у него в разных буквах `s` - в оопределении фцнкции и в вызове. В ожном месте `Sum`, в другом `sum`.

Comment: @Harry, у него две проблемы - одна в названии, а другая-то в этом.

Comment: @Harry, `_Sum уже определен в functions.obj
Testing
main.obj`

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо за ответ. Но проблема больше заключается в том возможно ли(и если возможно то как), сделать подключение файла .c. То есть через #include. P.S Функция было взята для примера.

Comment: @MacAntony, да, можно, но когда вы так делаете, не передавайте включаемый файл компилятору, или линкеру, т.к. определение 2х имен функций приведет к ошибкам, и еще совет, постарайтесь не использовать `Visual Studio`, либо используйте `CMake` проекты, тогда вы сможете контралировать какие файлы передаются компилятору/линковщику, а так же изучите все что связано с параметрами компилятора и линковщика. А для того что бы удалить файл из компиляции, нажмите на него ПКМ, и выберите пункт исключить из компиляции/проекта.

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, увидел ошибку компилятора и дальше не посмотрел :(

Answer (score 0):

В functions.c добавь

```
#pragma once
```

Ну и переименуй `Sum` в `sum`.

Comment: @Harry, ну это же `VS` она автоматом добавляет в компиляцию =)

Comment: компилит, компилит, судя по выводу линковщика

Comment: @Harry, VS компилирует. Читай ошибки внимательно: `_Sum уже определен в functions.obj
Testing
main.obj`